# Execute a php script when a javascript button is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm fairly new to web development, so I'm pretty sure I'm missing something here. I did try really hard to do it by my own means, but after 300 webpages in my history I decided to ask for help and move on.

**Problem:**
 I need to write a CSV file in my server with the data the user provides in a js form. I've seen this can be achieved including jquery and ajax in `index.php`, but im using html for the index. I've included jquery in the header. Developer tools says a post request is being made to `write.php` with

> status code 200(ok)

but nothing happens. If I type `localhost/write.php` an empty page appears

This is as far as I got.

In `index.html` :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function post()
{
var datos = $('#datos').val();
$.post('write.php',{postdatos:datos},
function(data)
{});
}


</script>
```

In `main.js` (where `#submit-button` is the button I need the php script executed on click) :

```
  function collectData() {
var nombre = $('#input-nombre').val();
var email = $('#input-email').val();
var telefono = $('#input-telefono').val();
var direccion = $('#input-direccion').val();
var pais = $('#input-pais').val();
var provincia = $('#input-provincia').val();
var ciudad = $('#input-ciudad').val();
var comoNosConocio = $('#dropdown-conocio').html();
var destinatario = $('#input-contacto').html();
var mensaje = $('#input-consulta').val();
  var datos = {
    'nombreYApellido': nombre,
    'email': email,
    'telefono': telefono,
    'direccion': direccion,
    'pais': pais,
    'provincia': provincia,
    'ciudad': ciudad,
    'comoNosConocio': comoNosConocio,
    'destinatario': destinatario,
    'mensaje': mensaje
  };
  //$.post('/write.php')

};  
console.log(datos);
```

}

```
  $('#submit-button').click(function () {
    collectData();
    post();
  });
```

`Write.php` contains:

```
<?php
echo "working";
?>
```

as I'm trying to even echo something out. I hope this is not a silly question because I spent 6 hours trying to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: where are you expecting to see "working" that's probably shown in dev tools to

Comment: 1. You define the variable `name` but don't do anything with it. 2. You use the undefined `datos` - variable in your `$.post`-method. 3. You have an empty callback method for your `$.post`-function which does nothing,

Comment: Im sorry, i left out the part of the code where datos is actually defined. Ill see the problem with the callback... I thought passing the php would make it run.  I do not see "working" anywhere. not even in dev tools

Comment: It might run... but if you don't catch the result and do something with it, what do you expect it to do? You won't see it in dev tools, since you're not logging it...

Comment: @MagnusEriksson "working" should be in the net-> response. assuming 200 in in the 'headers'  tab

Comment: I want to write it to a file on the server but I used echo for debugging hoping it would appear on the screen. I think my php script isnt running. I can see (the php code) it in network -> write.php -> response.
Im so sorry, Im really new to web dev and had to take this job.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson relax, i think your having a bad day,

Comment: Im sorry. It actually was a friend of mine who is an actual web developer and who ask me for help (we all agree it was a mistake for me to even accept) just to do the php script to write to a file. I thought it couldnt be hard. I edited the post and added the whole code i manage to put together.

Comment: @Dagon - You're right. I apologize. I've seen to many _"doesn't work"_ without explanation or people showing 2% of the code (or rewritten code for our benefit) today.

Comment: @PedroGagliardi - I apologize to you as well if I seem overly "bithcy". I just want to be able to help you to the best of my ability. :)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson not at all! Im new to stackoverflow and to web dev, so i get why someone could be annoyed. Maybe you could help me now, i added all you asked

Comment: Thanks. :) As far as I can see, your `collectData` doesn't return your `datos` value. You need to return it, store it in a variable in your submit callback and pass it through to your "post" function. Variables in js aren't global by default.

Comment: Btw. what is `$('#datos')` referring to? Do you have an input with that id that you save data to?

Comment: That was supposed to contain datos but i now feel dumb. Im sure thats not how you do it. I thought collectdata() made datos available within the document scope.  I feel i started with the wrong foot and tried too hard to fix it. Should have erased everything and start again. About write.php, i changed echo with alert("working"); but still nothing... Shouldnt that pop an alert ?